# Too many connections and iptables is not working to limit connections per ip

Tags: 14.04, networking, iptables

I have a dedicated server with 32GB RAM. It works all fine till some punters came to ddos my server. I had really high uplink bandwidth usage (over 150Mbps). I looked at netstat with the following command:

```
netstat -an | grep tcp | awk '{print $5}' | cut -f 1 -d : | sort | uniq -c | sort -n
```

It shows thousands of connections for multiple IPs: I used following iptable rules to limit connections per IP:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --syn --dport 80 -m connlimit --connlimit-above 15 --connlimit-mask 32 -j REJECT --reject-with tcp-reset 

iptables -A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -m limit --limit 150/second --limit-burst 160 -j ACCEPT
```

I saved these rules and these rules are top in the list in iptables. I restarted the system to close all the connects and restored the iptable rules. Put the server online. Server was almost dead and there were thousands of connections again. I have UFW installed and only couple of ports are open.

What can I do to stop it? How can kill established connections per ip? BTW. all the ips are masked and fake ones.

### Edit:

```
netstat -ant | awk '{print $6}' | sort | uniq -c | sort -n
      1 CLOSING
      1 established)
      1 Foreign
      2 SYN_SENT
      7 FIN_WAIT2
     16 LISTEN
     21 CLOSE_WAIT
     48 LAST_ACK
    209 SYN_RECV
    284 FIN_WAIT1
    772 ESTABLISHED
  35426 TIME_WAIT
```

Comment: Keep in mind the order of the rules is important: https://askubuntu.com/q/1210507/566421

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
/sbin/iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -i eth? -m state --state NEW -m recent --set
/sbin/iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -i eth? -m state --state NEW -m recent --update --seconds 60 --hitcount 10 -j DROP
```

The first line will Watch the IP connecting to your eth interface.

The second line will check if the connection is new within the last 60 seconds and if the packet flow is higher than ten and if so it will drop the connection.

To block IP address you must type:

```
/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -s xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx -j DROP
```

If you just want to block access to one port from an ip you must type:

```
/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -s xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx -p tcp --destination-port 25 -j DROP
```

The above rule will drop all packets coming from IP xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx to port 25.