# How can I remove an iptables rule?

Tags: 18.04, server, iptables

I would like to temporarily add the following iptables rule to see if allowing inbound traffic on port 5000 I will be able to connect to my docker container and the web server running within it:

```
$ sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 5000 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT
```

Then, if this attempt is unsuccessful, I would remove the above rule, but I do not know how to do it. 
I use `iptables-persistent` and, as suggested by [dokku documentation](http://dokku.viewdocs.io/dokku/getting-started/troubleshooting/), I do not use `ufw`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Append vs Insert**

Before I answer the question, let's look at the structure of the command:

```bsh
iptables -A INPUT 'the rule'
```

That means *`iptables`* `-A`ppend at the end of the `INPUT` chain the *following rule*. The other common way to add a rule to `iptables` is by the insert option:

```bsh
iptables -I INPUT 'the rule'
```

That means *`iptables`* `-I`insert at the beginning of the `INPUT` chain the *following rule*. Or when we want to insert the rule at certain place, for example before some existing rule that is number 3 in the chain:

```bsh
iptables -I INPUT 3 'the rule'
```

**The Numbers of the Rules**

The numbers of the rules plays significant role within `iptables` (*`ipchain`*). As illustration - let's say we have the following structure of rules:

```bsh
1. Deny all UDP 
2. Allow UDP on port 456
```

The UDP shouldn't be allowed on port 456, because it is already denied for all ports, so the structure must be:

```bsh
1. Allow UDP on port 456
2. Deny all (rest) UDP
```

If you want to read the structure of the chain `INPUT` use:

```bsh
sudo iptables -S INPUT
```

If you need to get the numbers of the rules, then you can use the command:

```bsh
sudo iptables -L INPUT -n --line-numbers # you can omit '-n'
```

**The Answer**

In order to delete some rule from a known chain, you can use the command:

```bsh
iptables -D CHAIN_NAME 'the rule'
```

That means *`iptables`* `-D`elete from `CHAIN_NAME` the *following rule*. Or in your case the command should be:

```bsh
sudo iptables -D INPUT -p tcp --dport 5000 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT
```

Also, you can delete the rule by its number within the chain, let's say it is number 3:

```bsh
sudo iptables -D INPUT 3
```

**As conclusion**

I'm sharing the opinion that, the tool Uncomplicated firewall - `ufw`, that is front-end of `iptables`, - sometimes can make the things much more complicated as they actally are :)

Here is a good article, provided by [DigitalOcean](https://www.digitalocean.com/?refcode=88ff80d60234), that describes the same as this answer, but in more details: [How To List and Delete Iptables Firewall Rules](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-list-and-delete-iptables-firewall-rules).

Comment: Great, informative answer!